# Do I need to create Database on each PC that uses my application?

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc, desktop-application

So here is the problem, I have created a simple standalone JAVA application that stores data for a billing system in database.
I am using SQLServer and Management studio on my PC for database functions.

1-Do I need to install SQLServer on Each PC that uses my application ?

2-How do I create Database on each Computer that uses my application when the user install it on their PC.

Comment: Must it be SQL-Server?

Comment: I meant do i need to install a DBMS on that PC ?

Comment: Check out SQLite if it doesn’t have to be SQL Server

Comment: If you use SQL-Server you have to install it on every PC. That's why you should consider other DB engines that don't need to be installed like SQLite.

Comment: It means i need to install SQL Server or the DBMS on each PC that uses my standalone application.  Right ?

Comment: do you want a central database where all PC can have access to or independent standalone database in every PC ?

Comment: Independent Standalone Database in every PC

Comment: I'm with @Brien on this one. Use SQLite. You just need to package the [SQLite JDBC Driver](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/) with your application. The database and table(s) can be quickly created dynamically (if it doesn't already exist in the system running the app).

Answer (score 0):

Q1: No, you do not need to install SQL Server for each PC. Your application would use a Driver (ex., JDBC Driver) to talk to the SQLServer DataBase over the network.

If you want to run some queries independent of your application from your PC you may need to install SQL Management Studio or other SQL tools.

Q2: The whole purpose of a database is that it can be used by many users and applications without having to install them on each machine.

Your DB can be installed on a 'Server' machine and the application can talk to the DB on that 'Server' machine.

It is too broad to discuss the many Application / Database deployment architectures here...

What you are describing is a typical class Client / Server architecture Where your application (the 'Client') talks to the Database (the 'Server').

Thanks.

Comment: My application is not Client \ server model, its a standalone application, So i guess i will need to install DBMS on each PC.

Comment: @WaqarAli That is unanswerable, it depends on what you mean with standalone. But if you really cannot have a central database, you should really consider using an embedded database like Apache Derby as a database and not SQL Server, so you won't need to install a database server at all.

Comment: @WaqarAli Standalone doesn't mean it can't be C/S ... Also, standalone application call DB (internally / externally too) ... Anyway, I agree with  here... You could choose the embedded DB approach too if that works for you... Thanks.